# Change values of a certain range of columns based on another range of columns of the same data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this df

```
       x      y1      y2        y3        y4             d1        d2          d3          d4
0  -17.7       7     NaN       NaN       NaN              5       NaN           4         NaN
1  -15.0     NaN     NaN       NaN         3              4       NaN         NaN           8
2  -12.5     NaN     NaN         2       NaN            NaN       NaN           1           9
```

I want only 1 value per row between `d1` to `d4`, based on what value is between `y1` to `y4`.

**Example:** In the 1st row, value is on `y1`. So the value that stays is `d1`.

The output would be:

```
       x      y1      y2        y3        y4               d1        d2          d3          d4
0  -17.7       7     NaN       NaN       NaN                5       NaN         NaN         NaN
1  -15.0     NaN     NaN       NaN         3              NaN       NaN         NaN           8
2  -12.5     NaN     NaN         2       NaN              NaN       NaN           1         NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `where` with a boolean matrix:

```
df[['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']] = df.filter(like='d').where(df.filter(like='y').notna().to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
      x   y1  y2   y3   y4   d1  d2   d3   d4
0 -17.7  7.0 NaN  NaN  NaN  5.0 NaN  NaN  NaN
1 -15.0  NaN NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN NaN  NaN  8.0
2 -12.5  NaN NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN NaN  1.0  NaN
```